# задача по ассемблеру(некоректно выводит результат)

Tags: ассемблер

Есть задание по ассемблеру:
Разработать функцию bool Bigleseq (byte * M1, byte * M2, short len), где M1, M2 - сверхбольшие целые положительные числа (байтовые массивы длиной len). Операция - если М1 <= М2, то значение Bigleseq - True, иначе - False. Должны использоваться команды для 32 разрядних данных. Если значение len не кратно 4, то при необходимости для сравнения последних байт использовать команды для 8-разрядных данных.Проблема в том что, при любом расскладе возвращается false.

```
.386
.model flat, C

.code
Bigleseq proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp;
    mov esi, [ebp + 16]  ;len
    and si, 11b
    mov ebx, [ebp+16]
    M1 EQU [ebp + 8]  ;m1
    M2 EQU [ebp + 12] ;m2

    clc
    start_32_loop:
        cmp ebx,[ebp+16]
        je NEW_FIRST_ITER
        popf
    NEW_FIRST_ITER:
        mov eax, dword ptr[M1+ebx]
        mov ecx, dword ptr[M2+ebx]
        cmp eax,ecx
        pushf
        jl Try
        jg False
        sub ebx,4
        cmp ebx,esi
        jg start_32_loop
        popf
        cmp si,0
        je Try
        mov bx,si
    start_8_loop:
        cmp bx,si
        je ITER
        popf
    ITER:
        mov ch,byte ptr [M1+ebx]
        mov ah,byte ptr [M2+ebx]
        cmp ch,ah
        pushf
        jl Try
        jg False
        dec bx
        cmp bx, 0
        jg start_8_loop
     Try:
        mov al,1
        jmp END_LABEL
     False:
        mov al,0
    END_LABEL:
    popf
    pop ebp
    ret
Bigleseq endp
end
```

Comment: Что значит "целые положительные числа" - это значит что они со знаком, но самый старший бит числа заведомо равен 0 или что они беззнаковые т.е. старший бит не знак, а обычный бит данных ? В любом случае в середине числа уж точно стоит использовать JA/JB для переходов как для беззнаковых данных, так как бита знака в середине числа точно нет. Если предположить, что числа беззнаковые, то везде использовать только JA/JB

Comment: И не делайте cmp si, 0 раз для длины числа используется esi целиком. Вы же проверяете только его младшую часть, при том что старшая может быть не нулевой. Если уж пишите 32 битную программу, то всегда работайте с регистром целиком, кроме тех случаев когда вам действительно нужна только младшая часть

Comment: Кстати, это повсеместная проблема в коде, например в самом начала and si, 11b оставит не измененными не только 2 младших бита числа в esi, но и все биты старше 16-го

Comment: И наконец главное, как вы тестировали свой код. пробовали ли его запускать когда одно число все 0, а другое целиком состоит из единичиных байт (0x01010101...) и потом то же самое но наоборот

Comment: Да, пробовала, оно всегда возвращает false

Comment: И да, они беззнаковые

Comment: Поменяла, не помогло(

Comment: Надо упрощать код. Для начала выбросьте все pushf/popf они не мешают, но и ничего полезного не делают. И самое главное, кажется я нашел проблему: вы зачем то используете EQU, но это директива времени компиляции, а не инструкция времени выполнения. вам передают адрес массива в [ebp+8], вы должны были взять его в какой нибудь регистр и потом использовать. А из за EQU `mov eax, dword ptr[M1+ebx]` разворачивается в `mov eax, dword ptr[ebp+ebx+8]` т.е. вы сравниваете какие то области в стеке, а не переданные массивы. И используйте отладчик, в нем бы сразу увидели такие проблемы ...

Comment: У меня есть вопрос, а могу ли я писать что то наподобии сmp dword ptr[eax+ebx],dword ptr[ecx+ebx]?Компилятор выдает ошибку

Comment: Всегда смотрите описания команд в интернете http://asmworld.ru/spravochnik-komand/cmp/  там видно какие параметры допустимы. r - регистр, r/m - регистр или память, imm - константа. Варианта r/m, r/m нет (собственно такого нет ни в одной инструкции). но есть r, r/m  так что `mov eax, dword ptr[esi+ebx]  /  cmp  eax, [edi+ebx]`  и да, я рекомендую для ссылок на массив использовать esi/edi - это их прямое назначение, а для хранения остатка длины выберите какой нибудь другой регистр, например edx

Comment: Cейчас попробую)

Comment: Помогло, спасибо вам большое)

Comment: Еще вопрос, когда числа равны компилятор указывает на ret  и ошибку высвечиват(

Comment: Вы pushf/popf все убрали, мне влом отслеживать все переходы в программе, но думаю в какой то момент вы переходите к точке end_label в состоянии когда все popf уже выполнены или pushf выполнен несколько раз, а popf меньшее кол-во раз. в итоге у вас неправильный указатель стека и ret не находит адрес возврата

Comment: Поняла, спасибо еще раз)